# not working PHP mysql array Search

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table

**Table School**

[image]

I want fetch Subject, When student login Class is a session.

For example student table is here

[image]

For example When Student 1 login his class7 is session, and i want all subject name from class7.

**My query :**

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `school` WHERE `class` IN ('$stu_class')");
```

Comment: do you have multiple comma seperated class name in a column in table school.??

Comment: yes i added query please check..Table school have multiple class and session is one Class ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MySQL `FIND_IN_SET()`. This function allow you to search key in comma separated value in a column.

Syntax :

```
   FIND_IN_SET(argument1,argument2)
```

argument1 is a string.

argument2 is a string list separated by comma.

find_in_set() function returns the position of a string within second string. Returns zero when search string doesn’t exist in string list.

```
 SELECT * FROM `school` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($stu_class, 'class');
```

In above query, `$stu_class` is your search key and `class` is your column name.

[Reference](http://webrewrite.com/find_in_set-function-in-mysql/)

Comment: i write 

SELECT * FROM `school` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($stu_class, `class`)

Getting error 

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: your next row have error which is some thing mysqli_num_rows(). what parameters have you passed

Comment: its normal like

 if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
} }

Comment: mysql_num_rows OR mysqli_num_rows  as for query you are using "mysqli"

Comment: Do one thing, in phpMyAdmin, fire query I have written., And see if that is proving perfect result or not